# Firebase Web not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I am trying to make a web site utilizing Firebass as my back end but I am having trouble reading data from the data base. I've double checked the paths and yes there is data there. If someone could give a quick look at what I am doing wrong I would really appreciate it. I am not getting any errors, its just not working.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script>
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
apiKey: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
authDomain: "my-app.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://my-app.firebaseio.com",
storageBucket: "my-ap.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "123456789"
};

</script>
<script>


function main(){
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    var database = firebase.database();
    var ratesRef = database.ref("users/rates");
    ratesRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot){
        console.log("Working");
        console.log("lat:" + snapshot.val().latitude);
    });
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="main();">
hello
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read from database, you need 2 callbacks, 1 for reading, 1 for errors. This will work for you:

`firebase.database().ref("users/rates").once('value', readFn(),errFn(errorObject))`

or replace main with this

```
function main(){
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var database = firebase.database();
var ratesRef = database.ref("users/rates");
ratesRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot){
    console.log("Working");
    console.log("lat:" + snapshot.val().latitude);
}, function(err) {console.log(err)});
}
```

You should also use once to prevent reading more than once when you request it

Comment: quick fix, in your second to last line you need to have err inside the console.log call. Other than that works great thanks!!

Comment: Thanks, forgot about that. Glad I helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all log your errors to see what happens.

`ratesRef.once('value')
.then(function(snap){...})
.catch(function(err){console.log(err)})`

Very probably you are getting permissions denied error as your security rules by default allow access for authenticated user.